# How to configure Electrum to open explorer in Tor Browser?

Tags: electrum, tor

Is it possible to configure Electrum to open explorer in Tor Browser?

I would like to use Blockstream’s http://explorerzydxu5ecjrkwceayqybizmpjjznk5izmitf2modhcusuqlid.onion/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Save the onion URL in preferences:

[image: Electrum-Preferences]

Electrum will use default browser to open explorer links. So, you will have to set the default browser as 'Tor Browser'. This can be different on every OS:

Ubuntu:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/542372/set-tor-browser-as-default-browser
https://askubuntu.com/questions/620955/how-to-change-priorities-of-x-www-browser

Windows: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4125/setting-tor-browser-as-default-browser-in-windows